# places of listener in java android studio

Tags: java, android, listener

when I replace "addOnFailureListener" and "addOnSuccessListener" in two different examples of the same code that I shared below, the top listener is wrong and the bottom one is not wrong. It hasn't happened to me before and I don't know what's causing it, what do you think I'm doing wrong?

```
public void submitLeaderboardScore(long score) {
            leaderboardsClient = Games.getLeaderboardsClient(getApplicationContext(), Objects.requireNonNull(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext())));

            leaderboardsClient.submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), score)
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // Handle failure while submitting score
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            // Score submission successful
                        }
                    });

        }

public void submitLeaderboardScore(long score) {
            leaderboardsClient = Games.getLeaderboardsClient(getApplicationContext(), Objects.requireNonNull(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext())));

            leaderboardsClient.submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), score)

                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            // Score submission successful
                        }
                    })

                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // Handle failure while submitting score
                        }
                    });


        }
```

[success listener on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCq7b.jpg)
[error listener on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEwNB.jpg)

error : Cannot resolve method 'addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener)'
or
Cannot resolve method 'addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener)'

whichever is on top, error is displayed on it

Comment: What is the return type of `leaderboardsClient#submitScore` ?

Comment: Both are wrong, the IDE only can signal the first wrong one, because it can't tell if the second is correct if the first one is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as follows

```
 leaderboardsClient.submitScoreImmediate(leaderboardId, score).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ScoreSubmissionData>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ScoreSubmissionData data) {
      
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
      
    }
});
```